# cannot execute java class from bash script and also updatd the java_home to higher version and compiled the class in the lower version than mentioned

Tags: java, unix

I had SunOs 5.10 unix server , where i  had written a script to execute a  java file which is as below

```
#!/bin/ksh -x

export  JAVA_HOME=openjdk1.8.0_331/bin

$JAVA_HOME/java com.myclass.MyClient
```

in this script there is alot of code which includes log file, and other binaries class path added before exporting JAVA HOME. But when i am executing i am getting the below error

```
openjdk1.8.0_331/bin/java : Cannot execute
```

i had changes lot of java versions but getting the same error

Comment: Is `openjdk1.8.0_331/bin` the correct path relative to your working directory?

Comment: As an aside, why did you tag `bash` but your shebang says `ksh`?

Comment: @Fedrico: yes path was right otherwise wewould get file does not exist

Answer (score 0):

- Your JAVA_HOME is not an absolute path. This is broken; many tools will just fail when you do this. Just make it an absolute path. It may or may not explain your error, but it's a ticking timebomb.
- JAVA_HOME cannot be `bin`; its the level above bin.

It looks like you're using `JAVA_HOME` as an ersatz script variable to make your script work, but this is wrong: `JAVA_HOME` is used by all sorts of tools and has a very specific meaning, and it's not whatever you think it is.

There are 2 obvious explanations for your error:

- Some tool sees `JAVA_HOME`, attempts to run java based on this, and fails, because your JAVA_HOME is broken. There's a ton of infra that is 'custom' per OS, and it may well be that the SunOS setup didn't fail if you set JAVA_HOME to broken values, but it does fail here. The fix is to not have broken JAVA_HOME, not to start looking for a setup on your new OS that can deal with broken JAVA_HOME settings. In other words, your script was always broken, it just so happens that your specific set up on that specific server on that specific version of sun OS so happened to be capable of dealing with the mess.
- A much simpler explanation is also possible: That executable does not run on your OS+Architecture combination. trivially testable: Do **NOT** set `JAVA_HOME` at all and just try to run that java executable by e.g. `cd` ing to the path and running `./java -version`. See what happens. If that also gives you `cannot execute`, voila - the script isn't the problem (though it still has a broken JAVA_HOME you should be fixing), you need to install a JVM that works on your OS+Architecture.

Comment: As you explained in 2nd point i had done cd and went to java bin folder and gave `./java -version`  it is giving invalid document but giving `java -version` it is providing the version.. but i didnt get your point broken JAVA_HOME menas or how to fix it

Comment: It should [A] be absolute and [B] not include the `bin` part.

Comment: I had given absolute path /home/apps/openjdk1.8.0_331.. but still the error exists.. While defining it to execute class file .. i had defined as `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java classname`.. but still giving the same error